# WatchOS3 Complication that launches App

Tags: swift, watchkit, launch, apple-watch-complication, watchos-3

I would like to create a complication for watchOS 3 that will simply launch my App. I have used XCode to create the ComplicationController:

```
class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource
{

    // MARK: - Timeline Configuration

    func getSupportedTimeTravelDirections(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void) {
        handler([.forward, .backward])
    }

    func getTimelineStartDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getTimelineEndDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getPrivacyBehavior(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior) -> Void) {
        handler(.showOnLockScreen)
    }

    // MARK: - Timeline Population

    func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the current timeline entry
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, before date: Date, limit: Int, withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the timeline entries prior to the given date
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, after date: Date, limit: Int, withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the timeline entries after to the given date
        handler(nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Placeholder Templates

    func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
        handler(nil)
    }

}
```

and added images for the Circular, Modular and Utilitarian assets. But when I run the Watch App I cannot select my complications for a Watch face. What do I still need to do?

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These code changes are required:

```
func getSupportedTimeTravelDirections(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void)
{
    handler([])
}


func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void)
{
    if complication.family == .circularSmall
    {

        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingImage()
        template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "Circular")!)
        let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
        handler(timelineEntry)

    } else if complication.family == .utilitarianSmall
    {

        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage()
        template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "Utilitarian")!)
        let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
        handler(timelineEntry)

    } else if complication.family == .modularSmall
    {

        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingImage()
        template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "Modular")!)
        let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
        handler(timelineEntry)

    } else {

        handler(nil)

    }

}


func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void)
{        
    switch complication.family
    {
        case .circularSmall:
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Circular")!
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallSimpleImage()
            template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
            handler(template)
        case .utilitarianSmall:
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Utilitarian")!
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallSquare()
            template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
            handler(template)
        case .modularSmall:
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Modular")!
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage()
            template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
            handler(template)
        default:
            handler(nil)
    }
}
```

Plus you need to provide the images as assets in the extension.

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal By default your complication images are in a `Complications` folder, so correct reference to images would in that case be
`let image = UIImage(named: "Complication/Utilitarian")!`

Answer (score 2):

Apple Watch 4 new graphic complications looks like this:

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the current timeline entry
    switch complication.family {
    case .graphicCorner:
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerCircularImage()
            let image = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Corner")!
            template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
            let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
            handler(timelineEntry)
        } else {
            handler(nil)
        }
    case .graphicCircular:
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage()
            let image = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Circular")!
            template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
            let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
            handler(timelineEntry)
        } else {
            handler(nil)
        }
    default:
        handler(nil)
    }
}

func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
    // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
    switch complication.family {
    case .graphicCorner:
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerCircularImage()
            let image = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Corner")!
            template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
            handler(template)
        } else {
            handler(nil)
        }
    case .graphicCircular:
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage()
            let image = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Circular")!
            template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
            handler(template)
        } else {
            handler(nil)
        }
    default:
        handler(nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Apple Watch 4 new graphic complications (watchOS 5.0+) and **prevent crash** on Apple Watch Series 1, 2 and 3.

Important: the [code from Zoltan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653060/2439941) will crash on Apple Watch series 3 or lower.

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/graphic), the new graphic complications require watchOS 5.0 or higher **and** a Watch Series 4 or later:

> **Note** Watch faces that support graphic templates are available only on Apple Watch Series 4 or later.

This means that a Watch Series 3 with watchOS 5 or 6 (due to `if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *)`) will attempt to load the complication image from the asset catalogue. However, since [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/404/) is enabled by default, the Watch Series 3 doesn't have the image in it's binary and therefor the following line will **crash** the app:

`let image = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Corner")!`

We discovered this when we found thousands of crash reports in Xcode:

1. Open Xcode
2. Window -> Organizer
3. Select tab "Crashes"
4. Select an App Store version

We found a crash report for each of the 2 Graphic complications that we support, all were with watchOS 5 or 6 and Watch Series 2 or 3, like:

[image]

**Solution**

Embed loading of the graphic asset within an IF statement and return `nil` as template, so it won't crash on devices without the asset.

The [example above from Zoltan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653060/2439941) will be:

```
case .graphicCorner:
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerCircularImage()
            if let image = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Corner") {
                template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)
            } else {
                handler(nil)
            }
        } else {
            handler(nil)
        }
```

For efficient and maintainable code, we created a reusable function `templateForComplication()` that is used in all 3 mandatory delegate functions:

```swift
class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {
    
    // MARK: Mandatory Delegate Methods
    
    func getSupportedTimeTravelDirections(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void) {
        // Turn off time travelling:
        handler([])
    }
    
    func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
        let template = templateForComplication(complication: complication)
        let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template!)
        handler(timelineEntry)
    }
    
    func getPlaceholderTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
        handler(templateForComplication(complication: complication))
    }
    
    func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        handler(templateForComplication(complication: complication))
    }
    
    
    // MARK: Helper Methods
    
    private func templateForComplication(complication: CLKComplication) -> CLKComplicationTemplate? {
        // Init default output:
        var template: CLKComplicationTemplate? = nil
        
        // Graphic Complications are only availably since watchOS 5.0:
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            // NOTE: Watch faces that support graphic templates are available only on Apple Watch Series 4 or later. So the binary on older devices (e.g. Watch Series 3) will not contain the images.
            if complication.family == .graphicCircular {
                let imageTemplate = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage()
                // Check if asset exists, to prevent crash on non-supported devices:
                if let fullColorImage = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Circular") {
                    let imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider.init(fullColorImage: fullColorImage)
                    imageTemplate.imageProvider = imageProvider
                    template = imageTemplate
                }
            }
            else if complication.family == .graphicCorner {
                let imageTemplate = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerCircularImage()
                // Check if asset exists, to prevent crash on non-supported devices:
                if let fullColorImage = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Corner") {
                    let imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider.init(fullColorImage: fullColorImage)
                    imageTemplate.imageProvider = imageProvider
                    template = imageTemplate
                }
            }
        }
        
        // For all watchOS versions:
        if complication.family == .circularSmall {
            let imageTemplate = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallSimpleImage()
            let imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "Complication/Circular")!)
            imageProvider.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            imageTemplate.imageProvider = imageProvider
            template = imageTemplate
        }
        else if complication.family == .modularSmall {
            let imageTemplate = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage()
            let imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "Complication/Modular")!)
            imageProvider.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            imageTemplate.imageProvider = imageProvider
            template = imageTemplate
        }
        else if complication.family == .utilitarianSmall {
            let imageTemplate = CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallSquare()
            let imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "Complication/Utilitarian")!)
            imageProvider.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            imageTemplate.imageProvider = imageProvider
            template = imageTemplate
        }
        
        return template
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@zoltan-vinkler's answer for Apple Watch 7

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the current timeline entry
    switch complication.family {
        case .graphicCircular:
            let image = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Circular")!
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage(imageProvider: CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image))
            let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
            handler(timelineEntry)
        default:
            handler(nil)
    }
}

func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the current timeline entry
    switch complication.family {
        case .graphicCircular:
            let image = UIImage(named: "Complication/Graphic Circular")!
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage(imageProvider: CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image))
            let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
            handler(timelineEntry)
        default:
            handler(nil)
    }
}
```